# Read clipboard not working in jupyter or terminal

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, python-3.5, jupyter

I was learning pandas and I am stuck with this read_clipboard issue.

```
nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()
```

this is the error that i get

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-cab596b16d61> in <module>()
----> 1 nfl = pd.read_clipboard()

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard.py in read_clipboard(**kwargs)
     18     from pandas.io.parsers import read_table
     19     text = clipboard_get()
---> 20     text = text.decode('UTF-8')
     21 
     22     # try to decode (if needed on PY3)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

**Part of clipboard.py file**

```
from pandas.util.clipboard import clipboard_get
from pandas.io.parsers import read_table
text = clipboard_get()
text = text.decode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Hi Aditya - what operating system are you using to develop on?

Comment: @PhilSheard Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception error message is telling you that you need some additional helper software installed:

```
"Pyperclip requires the gtk, PyQt4, or PySide module installed, or either the xclip or xsel command"
```

You could install any of these to get this working. As you're developing on Ubuntu, the simplest way would probably to install either `xclip` or `xsel`:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Comment: this worked when python3.8 pandas was putting pyqt4 not found error while using read_clipboard